# how to remove duplicate template arguments in template declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using-declaration

For conciseness sake I would like to name a template argument only once in its explicit instantiation, but I am getting a compiler error. I am attempting to use the C++ syntax as described in cppreference under `Type alias, alias template`. Here is my sample code:

```
struct M {};

template< typename T1 >
struct S {};

template< typename T2, typename T3 > 
struct N {};

// type alias used to hide a template parameter (from cppreference under 'Type alias, alias template')
//template< typename U1, typename U2 >
//using NN = N< U1, U2< U1 > >; // error: attempt at applying alias syntax: error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '<'

int main()
{
  N< M, S< M > > nn1; // OK: explicit instantiation with full declaration, but would like to not have to use M twice
  // NN< M, S > nn2; // desired declaration, error: error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '<'

  return 0;
}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typename U2` is a typename, not a template. Thus, `U2< U1 >` doesn't make sense. Replace it with a template template parameter:

```
template< typename U1, template<typename> class U2 >
using NN = N< U1, U2< U1 > >;
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/YQMUS40263)